Daily Pooja Mantra chanting
Namaskar.
I read an article that says we should never chant any mantra unless we receive Guru initiation, including Hanuman Chalisa.
In case of mispronounciation, there might be deva dosha and the wrong pronunciation will feed negative entities which is the same as inviting them to our place.
I don't know Sanskrit. Any Chanting I do, I try listening to the YouTube video and follow. Mostly I chant stotrams, nama japa and Hanuman Chalisa.
As I do not have much knowledge in this, after reading the article I would like to stop the chanting. Instead would like to opt to listening to stotrams/mantra.
Would like to know your thoughts if listening to them will have adverse effect mentioned above, the same as Chanting.

Relax chanting stotrams, naam japa or hanuman chalisa doesn't need any initiation, initiations are usually needed if you are doing some specific sadhanas using specific mantras coz every mantra has associated energies with it and that is why the pronunciation matters a lot and guru's guidance is must in that case. Stotrams are basically songs in praise of that specific deity. There is a sadhana app available where many mantras are available directly to end users given by Om Swami, try it out.

Let's start with what Vedas have to say:

अस्त्रा नीलशिखण्डेन सहस्राक्षेण वाजिना । रुद्रेणार्धकघातिना तेन मा सम्
अरामहि ॥11.2.7 Oh Rudra (रुद्र), with powerful/swift/impetuous (वाजिना
) mighty weapons (अस्त्र), with dark hair and chest (शिखण्ड) (or)
Bluish-Black turf ((नील +शिख) , thousand eyes (सहस्राक्ष ) (or)
dwelling in thousand places (सहस्र + क्षेण ), and inflictor/slayer
(घातिन्) of Ardhaka (अर्धक), in this way (तेन ) one who alters
(altering) and is improper (अराम ) chants the mantras (अर्धक)

So who ever told you about Mantra being given over by a Guru is correct. Its called Mantropadesha. However, that only applies to Veda Mantras and some designated Tantric mantras. Why? because of Phonics.
But the same mantras can be recited as a japa (internal emulation) and not outside chant. So many Bhakti Sages converted the Mantra Sara (the essence of mantaras) into Stotram, Stuti, Dandakas, Pattikas and more. Why? so that a common man without the need of a Guru can reminisce the same essence in leisure. Adi Shankara has bestowed the world with a diverse list of magnificent hymns filled with mantrasara.
Finally, pooja has many upasharas (services) that start with Deepa (fire oil lamp) and ends with udvasana (fairwell). 16 services are recommended at home called the Shodashopachara Puja. Out of 16, 5 are primary, and Devi is called by a title called "Panchopacharini", these 5 are, Doopa- Incense, Deepa -oil lamp, Gandhya -Sandalwood paste, Pushpa -flowers, Naivedyam -edibles). Each upachara has a mantra associated with it. These mantras can be recited internally with no harm, why? because pooja depends on Bhavana. That is why Devi is called "Bhavana Mantra Santusaya namaha" meaning with just Bhavana She will be pleased.
There might not be any "bhavana" involved in listening unless its Shravanam (link) in the form of Pravachanam (listening to accounts of Ishvara as a discourse) or Kirtanam (devotional hymns). Among the Nava-vidha Bhakti (9 approaches to devotion), there is Shravanam (listening). So the reader must understand that the goal of Nava-Vidha bhakti is Bhavana. Without bhavana its like a Amazon Alexa or Hello-Google device listening to random noise.
Source: link

In which part of your answer, it is answering this question: " Would like to know your thoughts if listening to them will have adverse effect mentioned above, the same as Chanting." ??

@TheLittleNaruto there might not be any "bhavana" involved in listening unless its Shravanam in the form of Pravachanam or Kirtanam. Among the Nava-vidha Bhakti. There is Shravanam (listening). So the reader must understand that the goal of Nava-Vidha bhakti is Bhavana. That is why I emphasized on it so much. Ears are always open, but Adi Shankara and other have been very critical about not allowing non-brahmins to listening to Vedic chants, such people would even get incacerated. So I cant write all that and discourage people in the name of 'QUOTES',  At the end its all Bhavana.

I) Your first question I read an article that says we should never chant any mantra unless we receive Guru initiation, including Hanuman Chalisa.
1) According to Sri Kulārnava Tantram (श्रीकुलार्णव तन्त्रम्) that asserts about mantra dīksha from a Guru as given below:

उपासनाशतेनापि याम् विना नैव सिद्यति ।
ताम् दीक्षामाश्रयेद् यत्नात् श्रीगुरोर्म सिद्धये ॥ १४.७७ ॥

That dīksha without which there is no Mantra Siddhi (मन्त्रसिद्धि/Fulfillment) 
even with hundred Upāsanās, should be obtained
from a competent Guru [सिद्ध गुरु], the one who has perfected/acquired
already the Mantra Siddhi for that mantra, for the success of the
mantra. ॥ 14.88 ॥

अनकेकोटिमन्त्राणि चित्ताकुलकराणि च ।
मन्त्रं गुरुकृपाप्राप्तमेकं स्यात् सर्वसिद्धिदम् ॥ १५.१९ ॥

Innumerable are mantras; they but distract the mind. Only that mantra
which is received through the Grace of the Guru gives all fulfilment.॥ 15.19॥


Beware-1: Sri Kulārnava Tantram (श्रीकुलार्णव तन्त्रम्) asserts with sloka [19] that you need initiation (Mantra Dīksha/मन्त्र दीक्षा) in order to carry out any Moola mantra japa alone. However Hanuman Chālisa does not fall under the category of Moola Mantra.
2) Guru initiation is required only for moola mantra japa in order to carry out for Tantra Sādhana to acquire Devata Vasyam (देवता वश्यम्) or Mantra Siddhi (मंत्र सिद्धि) of the devata concerned. Kulārna Tantra(कुलार्णव तंत्र) [chapter-15] says:

उपदेशस्य सामर्थ्यात्‌ श्रीगुरोश्च प्रसादतः । 
मन्त्रप्रभावाद्भक्त्या च मन्त्रसिद्धिः प्रजायते ॥ १३ ॥

Mantras fructify on the basis of the potency [samarthya/सामर्थ्य] of
the Instruction [upadesam], Grace [prasādam] of Sri Guru and the faith
[भक्त्या] of the devotee in the fructifying power of the Mantra [mantra siddhi/मन्त्रसिद्धि]
itself.॥ 13 ॥

and 3) The following sloka from Kulārnava Tantram [Ch-15, Sloka-21], says about which are the mantras recitable (without repetition nor japa carried out for devata siddhi) with bakthi bhāvana(भक्ति भावना/Devotional cultivation):

पुस्तके लिखितान्मन्तान् विलोक्य प्रजपन्ति ये ।
ब्रह्महत्यासम् तेषां पतकम् व्याधिदुःखदम् ॥ १५.२१ ॥

Those who seeing Mantras written in books, practice Japa of
them,commit a sin tantamount to brahmahatti [brahmanicide] resulting
in disease and misery.॥ 15.21 ॥


Beware-2: This implies that never do Japa of uninitiated Mantra. So, Kulārnava Tantram [Ch-15, Sloka-21] permits to chant Ashtottara Sata Namāvali, Sahasra Namāvali, Kavacha, Bhajan, Chālisa, Nama Japa, and Gāyatri mantra but never as Tantric Japa Upāsana.
II) Your second question In case of mispronounciation, there might be deva dosha and the wrong pronunciation will feed negative entities which is the same as inviting them to our place.
Kulārna Tantra(कुलार्णव तंत्र) [chapter-15] says that any wrong doing or break of rules will be wiped out through japa:

आब्रह्मबीजदोषाश्च नियमातिक्रमोद्धवाः । 
ज्ञानाज्ञानकृताः सर्व प्रणश्यन्ति जपात्‌ प्रिये ॥ ६ ॥

O My Beloved ! All blemishes due to transgression of rules, from Jīva
to Brahman, done knowingly or unknowingly, are wiped away by Japa.॥ 6 ॥

Beware-3: Many who have incomplete and shallow knowledge in Tantra Sastras utter such words as any flaws in mispronunciation, etc., will harm us. But the above sloka [6] guarantees that all blemishes due to transgression of rules will be wiped away through japa.
III) Your third question I don't know Sanskrit. Any Chanting I do, I try listening to the YouTube video and follow. Mostly I chant stotrams, nama japa and Hanuman Chalisa.
Kulārna Tantra(कुलार्णव तंत्र) [chapter-15] says that mantra is infructuous without a knowledge of its meaning:

मन्त्रार्थं मन्त्रचैतन्यं योनिमुद्रा न वेत्ति यः ।
शतकोटिजपेनापि तस्य सिद्धिर्न जायते ॥ ५९ ॥

If one does not know the meaning of the Mantra, the consciousness of
the Mantra and the Yoni-mudra, then even a hundred crore of its Japa
would not lead to success.॥ 59 ॥

Beware-4: Nāma-japa is the safest to chant because every body knows the meaning of the nāma!
Beware-5: Although the applicability of the above sloka is only for Moola mantra japa, it can be extended to stotram or Hanuman Chālisa not to recite without the understanding of their meaning.
It is suggested that after learning the meaning of strotam/Chalisa, you better begin to recite. YouTube video watching will be definitely helpful as far as pronunciation is concerned.
IV) Your fourth and final question As I do not have much knowledge in this, after reading the article I would like to stop the chanting. Instead would like to opt to listening to stotrams/mantra. Would like to know your thoughts if listening to them will have adverse effect mentioned above, the same as Chanting.
Since your lack knowledge in Sanskrit is definitely a setback, however you can pickup Sanskrit language at least to the level of correct pronunciation by attending Sanskrit classes for a couple of months. Of course, you may watch YouTube videos offering basic tuition for learning Sanskrit language. Let me suggest one such as video for you:

You can listen as well as chant; don't worry and just ignore those adverse effects because you are not dealing with Tantra Sādhana rather you chant Ashtottara Sata Namāvali, Sahasra Namāvali, Kavacha, Bhajan, Chālisa, Nama Japa, and Gāyatri mantra only with Bhakti Bhāvanā (भक्ति भावना/Devotional cultivation).
